# physically stretch plot in horizontal direction in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, stretch

I want a simple x,y plot created with matplotlib stretched physically in x-direction.
The intention is to get a result were it is easier for me to detect features in the signal.

So I don't want to change any scales or values or limits. Just change the distance between two gridpoint in my output file...

I want to do that on four subplots which should have the same size afterwards.

Thanks in advance... I tried for hours now and I think one of you could probably help me...

David Zwicker already solved my problem in this special case, thanks a lot for that, but in general... If I plot 2 subplots like in this code:

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)

plot(u_av,z)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)

plot(pgrd_av,z)

clf()
```

and want to stretch only one of them. What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly add axes to the canvas at an arbitrary position with [`plt.axes()`](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=pyplot.axes#matplotlib.pyplot.axes). For instance:

```
ax1 = plt.axes([0, 0, 3, 0.5])
ax2 = plt.axes([0, 0.6, 1, 1])
```

[image: Arbitrary axes]

Comment: I have exactly this problem but callings plt.axes() only deforms the location of my xlabel/ylabel/title. Meanwhile the neither the x or y axes are stretched.

Comment: ^ same w colorbar. This doesn't work if you have some other elements besides the ax.

Answer (score 17):

You can change the figure size by using `plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))`. See the [documentation of the figure command](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure).

Comment: ok that changes the size of my whole figure but what can I do if I wanted to adjust only one subplot? Is anything similar available for the subplot function?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Maybe you can post some example code and/or example images? This would certainly clarify your request. Generally, you can places axes any way you want. The axes_grid helpers are useful here, e.g. http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/examples/axes_grid/make_room_for_ylabel_using_axesgrid.html

Answer (score 10):

I know, this is a bit out of the context. But if someone is looking for a solution while using pandas plot which internally uses matplotlib. Here is the solution.

```
df.plot('col_x', 'col_y', title='stretched_plot', figsize=(20, 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
x = 1.5 # or your needed amount
plt.plot(x_array * x, y_array)
```

Your line or graph will move to the right depending on your x value